# Creating cakePHP 4 with php7.4 with error

Tags: cakephp, plesk, php-7.2, php-7.4, plesk-onyx

i tried to create a cakePHP project but i get this errors.

```
Problem 1
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-beta4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-beta3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-beta2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-beta1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-alpha2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-alpha1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-RC2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 4.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ^4.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[4.0.0, 4.0.0-RC1, 4.0.0-RC2, 4.0.0-alpha1, 4.0.0-alpha2, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.0.0-beta2, 4.0.0-beta3, 4.0.0-beta4, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6].


To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/zend_extensions_psa.ini
```

But i don't have php7.2 installed. I use php7.4. What can i do now?
I use Plesk Onyx with Ubuntu18.04. I couldn't find anything at CakePHP documentations.
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Does `php -v` confirm that you're running 7.4? Or do you maybe have 7.4 on the web server but 7.2 on the command line?

Comment: `php -v` says PHP7.2.24-0ubuntu.. Is there a way to change this? I am not very familiar with command line. Just learning by doing.

Comment: There are various ways to change it, but they can be very system-specific. Any chance that "php74" or "php7.4" work on the command line for you?

Comment: As i say i use Plesk as Hosting System and it seems that php7.2 is the only PHP version installed for command line. I will take a look if i can install 7.4 also.

Comment: It is working now. I installed the php7.4. for command line and some extensions. After that i am able to create a cakephp project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Install and enable the php `intl extension` in CLI and "Web" environment.
Be aware that you often have two different php.ini. One for CLI (command line) and one for "regular" PHP which runs on top of nginx or apache2.

After changing your configuration be aware to restart you apache2 / nginx or restart the server otherwise your changes have to effect.